# TS7006: Parameter 'copyMe' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a button which copies into clipboard content from variable using TypeScript. I tried this:

```
const [copySuccess, setCopySuccess] = useState('');

const copyToClipBoard = async copyMe => {
    try {
        await navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyMe);
        setCopySuccess('Copied!');
    } catch (err) {
        setCopySuccess('Failed to copy!');
    }
};
```

Button to call above code:

```
<Button                                    
    onClick={() => copyToClipBoard('some text to copy')}
>
    Copy Url
</Button>
```

I get error:

```
TS7006: Parameter 'copyMe' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Give it an explicit type of whatever you're expecting to call it with (string, by the looks of it)? Did you read up on that error code? Know how to type function parameters in general?

Comment: Yes, I expect String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an annotation:

```
const copyToClipBoard = async (copyMe: string) => {
    try {
        await navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyMe);
        setCopySuccess('Copied!');
    } catch (err) {
        setCopySuccess('Failed to copy!');
    }
};
```

Comment: One more thing. How I can add tooltip when I successfully copied the text? For example over the button?